# Stop page reload after submitting a value to PHP via Post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When I tried using other methods, either it did not stop the reload or the button stopped functioning. I have to POST data to php, which will perform actions to it. However, due to the page reload, the input value is applied to the new set of data, not the old one it was submitted on. The old data is replaced with new data randomly after the page reloads. Is there a way to stop the page reload using php? Here are some of the ways I tried:

1.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#form').submit(function () {
       $.post("header_html.php",$("#form").serialize(), function(data){            
     });
    return false;
    });
        </script>
  <!--html-->
  <form id="form" action="index.php">
        <input  style="width:200;margin-top:5px" type="text" class="form-control" id="code" name="installer2_code" placeholder="Enter Code">      
        <input type="submit" style="margin-top:5px" name="installer2_btn" class="btn btn-success" id="form" value="Enter" id="formbtn">
            </form>
```

2:

```
 $("#formbtn").click(function(){
   $.ajax({

method: "POST",

url: "index.php",

data: { name: $('#code').val()}

})

.done(function( msg ) {

alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );

});
})

<!--HTML-->
 <form id="form">
                <input  style="width:200;margin-top:5px" type="text" class="form-control" id="code" name="installer2_code" placeholder="Enter Code">


         <input type="button" style="margin-top:5px" name="installer2_btn" 
 class="btn btn-success" id="form" 
value="Enter" id="formbtn">
            </form>
```

Another method was the following but it stopped the button functionality.

```
 function sendForm(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

Method #4:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    $("#formbtn").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
           method: "POST",
           url: "index.php",
           data: { name: $('#code').val()}
       })
       .done(function( msg ) {
           alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
       });
    });

    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<form id="form">
    <input  style="width:200;margin-top:5px" type="text" class="form-control" id="code" name="installer1_code" placeholder="Enter Code">
    <input type="submit" id="formbtn" style="margin-top:5px" name="installer1_btn" class="btn btn-success" value="Enter">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
  $code_input = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
  return false;
```

Thanks for your help. I am open to any input.

Comment: have a look at AJAX and http://jquery.org

Comment: You are mixing two different technologies for sending data to the server - AJAX and HTML forms. Forms cause the postback (reload), AJAX does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your first example**

**1st** : you set two ids to input

```
<input type="submit" style="margin-top:5px" name="installer2_btn" class="btn btn-success" id="form" value="Enter" id="formbtn">
```

you need to remove `id="form"` from input

**2nd** : you need to use `e.preventDefault()` like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#form').submit(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var Form_data = $("#form").serialize();
       $.post("header_html.php", {Form_data : Form_data}, function(data){
          alert(data);          
       });
    });
</script>
```

and in php

```
<?php
  $form_data = $_POST['Form_data'];
?>
```

Personally .. while using `form` .. I prefer to use `form submit event` instead of `input click event`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#form').submit(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var Form_data = $(this).serialize();
     alert(Form_data);
     /*$.post("header_html.php",$("#form").serialize(), function(data){
       alert(data);
     });*/
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--html-->
<form id="form" action="index.php">
    <input  style="width:200;margin-top:5px" type="text" class="form-control" id="code" name="installer2_code" placeholder="Enter Code">      
    <input type="submit" style="margin-top:5px" name="installer2_btn" class="btn btn-success" value="Enter" id="formbtn">
 </form>
```

**In your second code**

**1st** : you set two ids to input

```
<input type="submit" style="margin-top:5px" name="installer2_btn" class="btn btn-success" id="form" value="Enter" id="formbtn">
```

you need to remove `id="form"` from input

**2nd** : you need to use `e.preventDefault()` like

```
$("#formbtn").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
       method: "POST",
       url: "index.php",
       data: { name: $('#code').val()}
   })
   .done(function( msg ) {
       alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   });
});
```

And while you using `url: "index.php",` that mean you pass the data to/from same page ... you'll need to use `return false;` in php .. so in `index.php`

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['name'])){
       echo ($_POST['name']);
       return false;
   }
?>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#formbtn").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var code = $('#code').val();
     alert(code);
     /*$.ajax({
         method: "POST",
         url: "index.php",
         data: { name: $('#code').val()}
     })
     .done(function( msg ) {
         alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
     });*/
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--html-->
<form id="form" action="index.php">
    <input  style="width:200;margin-top:5px" type="text" class="form-control" id="code" name="installer2_code" placeholder="Enter Code">      
    <input type="submit" style="margin-top:5px" name="installer2_btn" class="btn btn-success" value="Enter" id="formbtn">
 </form>
```

> **Important**: be sure that jquery included

Comment: The data does not pass, nor does the page stop refreshing. Are there some common ouside factors that may be impacting my code? Thanks!

Comment: @apaul answer updated with Demos hope this answer gives you a good information to help you understand how to prevent reload

Comment: Thank you so much. However, this isnt working either. I have edited my question to include the method you recommended and my recent code.

Comment: I believe I may have cornered the problem because when I performed the second snippet,  I did not receive an alert!

Comment: I fixed my jquery bug but now the functionality of the button is lost.

Comment: @apaul wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function(){ // code here })`